# How to apply same span to multiple strings in android?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have applied spans for making a string look , bold ,colorful and underlined,

```
String header1 = " HELLO "
SpannableString spanheader1     = new SpannableString(header1);

spanheader1.setSpan((new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER)), 0, spanheader1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanheader1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.header1_color)),0, spanheader1.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spanheader1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0, spanheader1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE ) ;
spanheader1.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanheader1.length(), 0);
```

Now i want to apply same spans to 10 other strings.

Do i need to write span sequence for each and every string or is there a way where i can apply same span settings to all of them at one go

Comment: So, you can create a function that takes in a String, and applies the same spans

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the same 'SpannableString' for multiple text views.
Like,

textView1.text = spanheader1
textView2.text = spanheader1